# GeoDjango GDAL error in terminal

Tags: django

I have an application which I wrote some months ago which included geodjango but I now visited the project today and ran the project in my terminal and got this error
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0", "gdal1.11.0", "gdal1.10.0", "gdal1.9.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.`
. I since dont know how to figure it out.

any help will be appritiated and further codes would be supplied on request

Comment: I want to completely remove the geodjango

Answer (score 3):

GDAL needs to be installed on your system. This installation process will vary depending on your operating system.

On Mac, you may simply install using brew:

```
brew install gdal
```